# How to denote Hilbert space when time is involved?

Tags: hilbert-spaces

For a linear system Au = b, if A is a square matrix in Hilbert space we can write 
$A \in \mathbb{R}^{H\times H}$.

However if u is time-dependent, can we write something like 
$u \in \mathbb{R}^{H\times T}$ where T denotes time?

I'm new to Math Stack Exchange, please forgive me if it's too simple, many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can write $u \colon \mathbb{R} \to H$, since (if I understand you correctly) $u(t)$ is an $H$-valued function of $t \in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, for a finite element problem, does $\mathbb{R}^{H\times H}$ denote an $H\times H$ matrix?

Comment: I don't really know what you mean by that. If you talk about a matrix, it should be with respect to some given basis for the space. If you just mean a linear operator on $H$, then one often writes $A\in L(H)$, for example.